# Error When Web API Help Tries to Deserialize Microsoft Azure AD Graph API Group

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

When I try to access the Help Area for my Web API 2 application, the HelpPageSampleGenerator is throwing an exception in the WriteSampleObjectsUsingFormatter method in the last line of the quoted code below when trying to deserialize a Group from the Azure AD Graph API:

```
        object sample = String.Empty;
        MemoryStream ms = null;
        HttpContent content = null;
        try
        {
            if (formatter.CanWriteType(type))
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                content = new ObjectContent(type, value, formatter, mediaType);
                formatter.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, ms, content, null).Wait();
```

Other classes (including those with nested classes) deserialize fine. I dug into the default object for a Group ("value" in the method call) and I do see this:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IGroupFetcher.AppRoleAssignments = '((Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group)(value)).Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IGroupFetcher.AppRoleAssignments' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

Since this is all Microsoft's code I don't think it's anything I'm doing. I'd really rather not have to write my own classes to parse into the Graph API's if I don't have to, but I will if there's no other work around.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the error when dig into this code `(Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group)(value)`?

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT no, the object itself is populated:
{Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group}
    base: {Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group}
    _appRoleAssignments: Count = 2
    _appRoleAssignmentsFetcher: null
    _description: "sample string 1"
    _dirSyncEnabled: true
    _displayName: "sample string 2"

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT I would provide the whole object but it's too long for the comment section.